# Learning Rate Callback on Step Rather Than Epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, callback

I have been trying to write a custom learning rate scheduler that updates every step rather than every epoch.

I have managed to implement the following learning rate scheduler that updates every epoch, yet cant figure out how to update learning rate every step?

```
LR_START = 0.00001
LR_MAX = 0.0001
LR_MIN = 0.00001
LR_RAMPUP_EPOCHS = 3
LR_SUSTAIN_EPOCHS = 0
WARMUP_STEPS = LR_RAMPUP_EPOCHS * (NUM_TRAINING_IMAGES//BATCH_SIZE)
TOTAL_STEPS = EPOCHS * (NUM_TRAINING_IMAGES//BATCH_SIZE)

def lrfn_epoch(epoch):
    if epoch < LR_RAMPUP_EPOCHS:
        lr = (LR_MAX - LR_START) / LR_RAMPUP_EPOCHS * epoch + LR_START
    elif epoch < LR_RAMPUP_EPOCHS + LR_SUSTAIN_EPOCHS:
        lr = LR_MAX
    else:
        #cosine decay
        progress = (epoch - LR_RAMPUP_EPOCHS) / (EPOCHS - LR_RAMPUP_EPOCHS)
        lr = LR_MAX * (0.5 * (1.0 + tf.math.cos(np.pi * ((1.0 * progress) % 1.0))))

lr_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lrfn_epoch, verbose = True)
```

This is the function I have to update the learning rate on every step.

```
def lrfn_step(step):
    if step < WARMUP_STEPS:
        lr = (LR_MAX - LR_START) / WARMUP_STEPS * step + LR_START
    else:
        progress = (step - WARMUP_STEPS) / (TOTAL_STEPS - WARMUP_STEPS)
        lr = LR_MAX * (0.5 * (1.0 + tf.math.cos(np.pi * ((1.0 * progress) % 1.0))))
    return lr
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

Here is the code to write a callback that updates on each step rather than each epoch.

```
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, schedule):
        super(CustomCallback, self).__init__()
        self.schedule = schedule
        self.epoch = 0
        
    def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
        actual_step = (self.epoch*STEPS_PER_EPOCH) + batch
        # Call schedule function to get the scheduled learning rate.
        scheduled_lr = self.schedule(actual_step)
        # Set the value back to the optimizer before this epoch starts
        tf.keras.backend.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, scheduled_lr)
        if batch == 0:
            print("--Learning Rate: {:.6f} --".format(scheduled_lr))
        
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.epoch+=1
```

And here is how to use it when fitting the model.

```
history = model.fit( ..
                     ..
                     callbacks = [CustomCallback(lrfn_step)],
                     ..
                   )
```